# RabbitMQ.Client ConnectionFactory missing Hostname property?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

According to the documentation here:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html

I am supposed to build a `ConnectionFactory` like so:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.UserName = user;
factory.Password = pass;
factory.VirtualHost = vhost;
factory.HostName = hostName;
```

This appears to be the official documentation, yet the assembly that I got from NuGet does not have a public `HostName` property for `ConnectionFactory`.

Is this a bug?  Is there a change in behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property hasn't changed in many years. The property is used all over the place, including in [our tutorials](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/dotnet/NewTask.cs#L9) and projects such as EasyNetQ (that depends on the .NET client).

So this is most likely an environment-specific issue.

Comment: It was an environment issue; for some reason Resharper didn't see the properties, but they were there and it built just fine.

Comment: the tutorials link is broken. I'm trying to deal with a similar issue!